# Websockets listen to server changes

Tags: javascript, websocket

Looking forward to all of you to provide some examples, where websockets are listening to server changes, i.e. client is notified when something changes on the server side in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

They all listen to server sent messages (as well as send their own)...

You can find some demos and read their code at: [www.websocket.org/demos](http://www.websocket.org/demos.html)